# Xcode: How to duplicate a file in File Inspector?

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode10.2

How to duplicate a file/class inside File Inspector of Xcode?

I've tried using CMD+C then CMD+V but it did not worked?

Answer (score 0):

It's really annoying I know that this does not work. However, as a workaround, try finding the file in finder and right-clicking / two-finger-clicking it there and selecting Duplicate.

UPDATE: I have found that if you use the keyboard shortcut Command + Shift + S while selecting the file it will duplicate (go to file -> Duplicate)

Answer (score 0):

Dragging file to a desired position in file inspector while holding `option/alt` key will duplicate the file.

If you drag file inside the same folder in the file inspector it will add a **`copy`** suffix to its name to prevent file name collission otherwise just copy it to new place.